# How to increase max buffer size in ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

In my custom GatewayFilter, that extends ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory, when I filter request heavier than 256 kb, I get DataBufferLimitException:

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:99)
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.updateCount(LimitedDataBufferList.java:92) 
...
```

I tried to use property

```
spring.codec.max-in-memory-size=5MB
```

and tried to change the limit in configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

But none of this worked. How can I increase max buffer size for my filter?
I saw solution for Modify**Response**BodyGatewayFilterFactory https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1658#issuecomment-678023793, but don't know how to implement it for my Modify**Request**BodyGatewayFilterFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I needed to have the following configuration as in my question:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

And autowire to filter constructor `ServerCodecConfigurer codecConfigurer` and call parent's constructor `super(codecConfigurer.getReaders());`

Comment: Having the same issue. Can you add the full filter code?